# How do I to display data from Firestore on frontend

Tags: angular, firebase

[image]I'm trying to make a quiz, and I've got a database filled with questions which I'm trying to display in the frontend. I am able to display the id of the questions, but not the actualQuestions. This is the typescript code:

```
    if(this.questionNumber !== this.questions.length - 1){
      this.questionNumber++;
      this.selectedQuestion = this.questions[this.questionNumber]
      console.log(this.selectedQuestion.payload.doc.id)
      this.questionAt++;
    }
    else{
      console.log("cant increase on selected array");
    }

  }
  previous(){
    if(this.questionNumber !== 0){
      this.questionNumber--;
      this.selectedQuestion = this.questions[this.questionNumber]
      console.log(this.selectedQuestion.payload.doc.id)
      this.questionAt--;
    }
    else{
      console.log("cant select -1 from an array");
    }

  }
```

And I'm trying to display it in the place of the id in the following code:

```
 <div class="modal-header">
            <h3><span class="label label-warning" id="qid">{{questionAt}}/10</span> {{this.selectedQuestion.payload.doc.id}}</h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: put your questions array

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: @Ramesh added an image of the db

Comment: @Electron I added an image of the db

Comment: hmm, so what's happening when you're trying to display the question using string interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to display an array of strings(questions) in the HTML you can do:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions">
  {{ question.actualQuestion }}
</div>
```

obviously replace the div with whatever you like.